# Browserstack local connection issue

Tags: cypress, browserstack

I am trying to run cypress based tests on Browserstack from behind proxy and have successfully started the local connection with

```
./BrowserStackLocal --key YOUR_ACCESS_KEY --local-identifier CypressLocalConnection1
```

When I tried starting the tests I get the error

```
[3:00:32 PM] - info: Validating the config
[3:00:34 PM] - info: Setting up Local testing...
Got Error in binary downloading request { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 11.111.111.11:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1111:11)
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '11.111.111.11.35',
  port: 443 }
Retrying Download. Retries left 5
```

My local settings is as below:

```
    "connection_settings": {
        "local": true,
        "local_identifier": "CypressLocalConnection1"

    },
```

How can the error be resolved?